# PayPal Payments Standard `currency` Variable is ignored

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to use PayPal as my payment gateway in my webform application, using the URL below:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=lola@revealhairandmakeup.com&first_name=&city=&state=&item_name=Wig%20Purchase%20on%20Reveal%20Hair&amount=320&night_phone_a=&item_name=Wig%20Purchase%20on%20Reveal%20Hair&address1=&shipping=0&handling=0&tax=0&quantity=1&currency=GBP&return=http://www.bankyfootwear.com/success&cancel_return=http://www.bankyfootwear.com/failed
```

But instead of giving the quoted amount in Pounds(GBP) it is in dollars(USD). I did set the currency above to 'GBP'. What am I doing wrong?

Here's an image of the PayPal Checkout page

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The parameter you are looking for is `currency_code`, not currency.

See the documentation at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/

Comment: Thanks a million, it worked. Im greatful!